# Where does DI fit in with CQS?

Tags: dependency-injection, command

Must you resort to property injection whenever a command requires a dependency?

Say I have the following command.

```
public class AddReviewCommand
{
    private ISession _session;
    private readonly string _reviewSummary;

    public AddReviewCommand(string reviewSummary)
    {
        _reviewSummary = reviewSummary;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var review = new Review
            {
                AddedBy = Environment.Username,
                AddedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                ReviewSummary = _reviewSummary
            };

            _session.Save(review);
    }
}
```

Is the only way to inject `ISession` is by property injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Property Injection** implies that the dependency is **optional**, which is rarely the correct invariant. **Constructor Injection** is a much more appropriate pattern:

```
public class AddReviewCommand
{
    private ISession _session;
    private readonly string _reviewSummary;

    public AddReviewCommand(string reviewSummary, ISession session)
    {
        _reviewSummary = reviewSummary;
        _session = session;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var review = new Review
        {
            AddedBy = Environment.Username,
            AddedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            ReviewSummary = _reviewSummary
        };

        _session.Save(review);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I asked is say I have a form that could execute one of several commands. I can't imagine injecting each command into my service (or whatever) constructor.

Comment: Why not? A few wouldn't be a problem. If you have too many, wouldn't it be a signal that the service itself violates the SRP?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for the comment.